# Javascript append array to array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to add new value to a pre-defined array of object like this:

```
$scope.chartConfig.series.push(
    [{
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: []
    }]
);
```

I want to add a new array value like so to `data` but keep failing. I've tried:

```
$scope.todayChartConfig.series['data'] = [];
$scope.todayChartConfig.series['data'].push(
    {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    }
);
```

But it append to a new object instead of combine with the current data array.

What I expect is:

```
[{
  name: "Brands",
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: [
    {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    }
  ]
}]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: With your current data structure, it should be: `$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0][0].data.push(...)` but I'm not sure if you really intended that 2D array

Comment: @ChrisMartin I'm using angular.

Comment: I'm confused. By your first example, it would appear that the `series` property is an array of arrays of objects. But in your second example, `series` appears to be an object that you're trying access a property on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current data structure it should be:

```
$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0][0].data.push(
    {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    }
);
```

Which should work because:

```
$scope.chartConfig.series.push(
    [{
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: []
    }]
);
```

pushes an array of object into an array.

However, if the above code is a typo and what you really intended was:

```
$scope.chartConfig.series.push(
    {
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: []
    }
);
```

then it should be:

```
$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0].data.push(
    {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    }
);
```

Comment: Works perfect. nope its not a typo. Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome. It just looked weird to me that's all :)

Comment: Yeah. When I look my code, I got a headache too. lol. Need to refactor them. Thanks for the heads up!. :D

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that `todayChartConfig.series` is an array so you should be appending to `$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0]`.

The second issue is that you need to append the objects individually. (**Not true. See edit below**)

So, this should work:

```
$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0]['data']
   .push({
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    }).push({
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    });
```

**Edit**: You can also append the objects all together (see @slebetman's comment below). So, this works too

```
$scope.todayChartConfig.series[0]['data']
.push({
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    });
```

Comment: This answer is wrong because `Array.push()` actually can accept multiple arguments

Comment: `data = []`. So, `data.push([1, 2])` results in `[[1, 2]]` and not `[1,2]`. Sounds like @SSuhat wants the latter and not the former hence the requirement to push individually.

Comment: No. It's `data.push(1,2)` not `data.push([1,2])`

Answer (score 1):

Your original array is $scope.chartConig.series, and then you're pushing onto $scope.todayChartConfig.series. Your problem is that you're not pushing onto the correct array.

You need to do:

```
$scope.chartConfig.series['data'] = [];
$scope.chartConfig.series['data'].push(
    {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        y: 56.33
    },
    {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 30.12
    }
);
```

To do what you want to do, see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdamAxtmann/b4kLs9w9/)